# Instalação phalcon-devtools

Tags: php, framework, phalcon-php

Boas pessoal,

Estou a tentar instalar o phalcon-devtools no xampp e estou a fazer o que a documentação oficinal diz para fazer [Aqui.](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/wintools.html)

Já configurei o xampp com a dll do phalcon e já fiz um mini projecto, mas queria o devtools para ajudar em algumas coisas.
Só que quando faço o comando phalcon após seguir a documentação ele diz:

"ERROR: Phalcon extension isn't installed, follow these instructions to install it: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html"

Já vi alguns video de pessoal a instalar quase da mesma maneira e que funciona... Não percebo o erro.

Tentei basear neste video, mas sem sucesso também:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fis0KkjxArQ

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui achar uma solução, ao que parece quando executava o código phalcon no cmd ele não detectava a dll no servidor xampp.

Por isso comecei a usar o ampps e segui a documentação e funciona bem.

Penso que o erro pode ser na declaração dos caminhos no Enviroment Variables...

Espero que possa ajudar mais pessoas!

Abraço